# Android Parse don't get push notfication

Tags: android, parsing, crash, push

I've launched Parse into my application, and then I pushed a notfication from theyr'e website, and from some reason I don't get it.
Although it shows in the site that the status is on "Dont", I don't get it.
Then I looked On the logcat, maybe something in my code isn't good.
Then it shows me that I need to make sure that I have some permmission on The Manifest... then I looked over it and still didn't find out what's missing\wrong.
What's to change/Check again to get the push notfication?

MainActivity

```
   package nir.rauc.mapstutori;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Parse
        Parse.initialize(this, "DontRightitonstackoverflow",
                "DontRightitonstackoverflow");
        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("Hello", "What's up my nigga");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, Pictures.class);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        // Google Maps things

        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng rent = new LatLng(31.732703, 35.182333);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(rent, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("for Rent").draggable(true)
                .snippet("Click for more info.").position(rent));
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Details.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        ;
    }
}
```

my Manifest :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nir.rauc.mapstutori"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutoris.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBpdh2ViLlc-UvlGBNaiFBZTZNOWpJBDyc" />

        <activity
            android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.Details"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.Pictures"
            android:label="something" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Logcat of errors:

```
  04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <uses-permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802):   <intent-filter>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802):     <category android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802):   </intent-filter>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(2802): </receiver>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):   <intent-filter>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):     <category android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):   </intent-filter>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): </receiver>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): To enable PPNS support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):   <intent-filter>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):     <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802):   </intent-filter>
04-13 00:08:38.129: E/com.parse.PushService(2802): </receiver>
04-13 00:08:38.509: E/SELinux(2907): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-13 00:08:38.604: E/EnterpriseContainerManager(2964): ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
04-13 00:08:38.699: E/SELinux(2922): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-13 00:08:38.859: E/SELinux(2935): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-13 00:08:39.109: E/SELinux(2980): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-13 00:08:40.054: E/APKPackageMonitor(7355): Some unrelated APK installed
04-13 00:08:40.554: E/app2sd(2223): GET ROOT = false
04-13 00:08:40.569: E/app2sd(2223): GET ROOT = false
04-13 00:08:50.254: E/WifiWatchdogStateMachine.QualitySocketHandler(2964): No http request!
04-13 00:08:58.849: E/Watchdog(2964): !@Sync 264
04-13 00:09:28.849: E/Watchdog(2964): !@Sync 265
04-13 00:09:58.854: E/Watchdog(2964): !@Sync 266
04-13 00:10:28.849: E/Watchdog(2964): !@Sync 267
04-13 00:10:46.289: E/AudioResampler(2499): Unsupported sample format, 1 bits, 2 channels
04-13 00:10:58.854: E/Watchdog(2964): !@Sync 268
04-13 00:11:28.854: E/Watchdog(2964): !@Sync 269
```

Comment: Doesnt this `android:name="com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"` has to use your "nir.rauc.mapstutori" package?

Comment: I saw in the website of them to keep it this way. check it right now.

Comment: try to change to your own package anyway

Comment: change it to :
<permission
        android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Send a push notfication,But still not working.

Comment: it has 2b "nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"

Comment: what? I do not Understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest should be like:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="nir.rauc.mapstutori"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true" />

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="11"
                android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:largeHeap="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

                <activity
                    android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="AIzaSyBpdh2ViLlc-UvlGBNaiFBZTZNOWpJBDyc" />

                <activity
                    android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.Details"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_details" >
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.Pictures"
                    android:label="something" >
                </activity>

                <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
     <category android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori" />
   </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

                <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

            </application>

        </manifest>
```

Comment: Still not working. I edited my android manifest so please Check it.

Comment: But still you has <uses-permission android:name="nir.rauc.mapstutori.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> remove pushnotifications. to make "nir.rauc.mapstutori.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"

Comment: Deleted it and still not working. Updating again the Manifest.. god Im frustrated from it

Comment: Are you getting the same error still? Remove my part of <receiver>. Actually the error message says exactly what you have to check in your manifest.

Comment: I suggest you to copypaste everything from shown logcat to your manifest to make sure.

Comment: I did it. I also Updated my LogCat Above.

Comment: Is google PlayServices added to a project? This might be an issue. And you didnt remome my part or receiver which starts with  <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"

Comment: I don't Remember what was there before. I thing this is good no? and google play services indeed in the android private libraries

Comment: I had refreshed my answer with your manifest compiled according to logcat message.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parse.initialize(this, "DontRightitonstackoverflow",
                "DontRightitonstackoverflow");
```

Should be in MyApplication.class
also add to manifest:

```
   <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen" >
```

here is My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR_PACK_NAME"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.anywall.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission android:name="com.parse.anywall.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following permission is not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but is recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "YOUR_PACK_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".

    -->
    <permission
        android:name="YOUR_PACK_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACK_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SampleActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "YOUR_PACK_NAME" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="YOUR_PACK_NAME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".PostActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_post" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AdminBrowserActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin_browser" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```